# How to remove the ~ denoted files from my directory using linux command?

Tags: linux, filenames

Why the files are created with ~ symbol?

By removing ~ symbol file will it affect the original file or it won't?

My files:(obtained by linux command ls)

```
DG_Item122   DG_Item147   DG_Item175   DG_Item200   DG_Item226   DG_Item249~  DG_Item271~  DG_Item293~  DG_Item314~  DG_Item49    DG_Item80
DG_Item122~  DG_Item148   DG_Item175~  DG_Item200~  DG_Item226~  DG_Item25    DG_Item272   DG_Item294   DG_Item315   DG_Item5     DG_Item80~
```

My expected output:

Files to be printed without the tilde.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing files with certain text editors, the editor may save a *backup* of the file with a `~` suffix. Other editors may use other suffixes, but `~` is by far the most commonly used backup suffix on Unix.

You may remove these files if you feel that you don't need the backups any longer:

```
$ rm *~
```

If you wish to keep the backup files, but don't want to see them in the output of `ls`, then you may use

```
$ ls -B
```

or

```
$ ls --ignore-backups
```

(which is the same thing).  These flags will make `ls` ignore files specifically matching the shell filename globbing pattern `*~` (since it's such a common backup suffix). To hide the listing of any other files, use e.g. `--hide='*.bak'` instead (this will hide any file with a `.bak` suffix). The `-B` and `--ignore-backups` flags may be seen as shorthands for `--hide='*~'`.

To avoid having to type `-B` every time, you could add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
function ls {
  command ls --ignore-backups "$@"
}
```

This will effectively "replace" the `ls` command with a shell function that calls the real `ls` with the `--ignore-backups` flag added.

Instead of a shell function, you could instead add an alias:

```
alias ls='command ls -B "$@"'
```

... if you think that looks neater.

Note: The `-B`/`--ignore-backups` options, as well as `--hide`, are GNU extensions to `ls` available in the `ls` implemented by the GNU coreutils package, but this will most likely already be installed on your Linux machine anyway.

As to aliases vs. shell functions, the `bash` manual contains the phrase

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Answer (score 1):

These files are typically created by some text editors and it means that they are backups of your original files.

If you don't want to see those files when `ls`:

```
ls | grep -v '~$'
```

or with GNU `ls`:

```
ls --hide='*~'
```

If you want to remove them:

```
rm ./*~
```

Removing them won't affect your original files (the ones without ~ at the end)

Comment: By removing will it affects the original file

Comment: @examplefile See my answer updated.